# Google Signin not working in release mode getting platformException

Tags: flutter, google-signin

Here is my Google signin code:

```
Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    setState(
          () {
        isLoadingGoogleLogin = true;
        vnForPreventClickWhenLoading.value = true;
      },
    );
    googleSignIn.signOut();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
    await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleSignInAccount?.id == null) {
      setState(() {
        isLoadingGoogleLogin = false;
        vnForPreventClickWhenLoading.value = false;
      });
    }
    Constant.ISGOOGLELOGIN = await googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount?.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication?.idToken,
    );
    final UserCredential authResult =
    await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final User? user = authResult.user;
    if (user != null) {
      // Checking if email and name is null
      assert(user.email != null);
      assert(user.displayName != null);
      assert(user.photoURL != null);
      socialName = user.displayName;
      SocialEmail = user.email;
      socialImageUrl = user.photoURL;
      socialPhoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
      socialRefreshToken = user.refreshToken;
      socialUid = user.uid;
      // Only taking the first part of the name, i.e., First Name
      if (socialName!.contains(" ")) {
        socialName = socialName?.substring(0, socialName!.indexOf(" "));
      }
     
  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
  final User? currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
  assert(user.uid == currentUser!.uid);
  log('signInWithGoogle succeeded:$user', name: TAG);
  Constant.socialImage = user.photoURL!;
  return user;
} else {
  setState(() {
    isLoadingGoogleLogin = false;
    vnForPreventClickWhenLoading.value = false;
  });
}
return null;
}
```

I have already added SHA-1 key in firebase console, still I get this error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed,
> com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 10: , null, null)
> #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653)
> #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296) 
> #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:499) 
> #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:280) 
> #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:431)

I have already added SHA-1 key in firebase console

Answer (score 0):

```
// function to implement the google signin
```

// creating firebase instance
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;